# Laravel Enviroment Variables are not working within Google Cloud Run

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-platform, laravel-8, google-cloud-run

I've deployed too many times Laravel projects up to Cloud Run successfully, but right now

It looks like Cloud Run is unable to read Enviroment Variables (which i've specified already in the Variables&Secrets section within Cloud Run instance).

[image]

I'm using Laravel 8. For testing purposes (and make sure Cloud Run it's reading env variables), i've added a simple route in the `api.php` section like belows:

```
Route::get('/test-env', function () {
    echo 'debuggeando<br>';
   dd(config('variables.test_env'));
});
```

Into my `config/variables.php` i've the follows:

```
<?php
return [
    'test_env' => env('TEST_ENV', 'no se encontro la variable')
];
```

And this is my final result:

[image]

What do am I doing wrong? Why Cloud Run is unable to read the enviroment variables from Laravel?

Answer (score 1):

You can only make Laravel pick up envirnmental variables, but not the other way around.

```
config(['test_env' => getenv('TEST_ENV')]);
```

Running `php artisan config:clear` & `php artisan config:cache` might be required. Another option might be to generate a fresh  `.env` file during the deployment, which merely translates to: already defining the value, before it can be cached.

Comment: Thanks. The fact is that any environment variables in the whole Laravel project are not detected from Cloud Run (that's includes all APP_ENV variables to make Laravel work). My TEST_ENV variable i've made it for test purposes.  I can't do any php artisan commands into Cloud Run because i build my project into a Dockerfile and then, Cloud Run take that file and upload it and build it up as a container.